# Ionic 3 App Size for android is more then compared to ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in Ionic for couple of months. I developed ionic 2 App with more 10pages and App size was 6Mb after Apk Generated, but in ionic 3 I have not even used more than 8pages and less lines of code then compared to Ionic 2 App. Still my Ionic 3 App Size is 35Mb. Any solution for this?

Note: No images are used for both App,

and is it required to keep `.module.ts` in all the pages which is new feature in Ionic 3.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build your project using below `CLI`: It builds the application for production with very small package size. You can see all the [**build CLI options here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/).

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

**Q:** is it required to keep `.module.ts` in all the pages which is new feature in Ionic 3?

**A:** This is not a must thing. But it is a really awesome feature. It will significantly boost your app's performance.You can read more about [**lazy loading here**](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` in your new project. This plugin usually adds ~20-30MB to your final .apk size.

You will need an angular-module for every page that has an `@IonicPage` decorator. The main advantage of this is that you can utilize lazy-loading (load pages when they are needed, not all of them when the app starts) when you just push a string onto the nav-stack like this: `this.nav.push('IonicPageName')`. And of course you have a modularized application which is always good from architecture point of view.

Have a look at the following blog entries by the ionic-team on lazy-loading

- [Part 1](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)
- [Part 2](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)